# Ktor: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column products.customer_id does not exist

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, crud, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I'm writing CRUD operations,and have 2 tables,**Customers and Products**.I've finished crud with Customer works great,but some problems with Products.***I use Kotlin/Ktor/Exposed/Postgres.***how the relationship works in ktor?I tried many times to rewrite ProductService,when i send get request(just for checking the routes),i receive(500 internal server error) or send post request,I received Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column products.customer_id does not exist.

model/Products.kt

```
package com.testreftul.model

import com.testreftul.model.Orders.references
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Column
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.ReferenceOption
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table


object Products:Table("products"){
    val id: Column<Int> = integer("id").autoIncrement()
    val product_name: Column<String?> = varchar("product_name", 255).nullable()
    val user_id: Column<Int> = integer("customer_id").references(User.id, onDelete = ReferenceOption.CASCADE)
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id,name = "PK_product_id")
}
@Serializable
data class  Product(
    val id: Int,
    val food_name:String,

)
```

model/User.kt

```
package com.testreftul.model
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Column
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.ReferenceOption
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table

object User:Table("customer"){
    val id: Column<Int> = integer("id").autoIncrement()
    val fullName: Column<String?> = varchar("full_name", 255).nullable()
    val email: Column<String?> = varchar("email", 255).nullable()
    val direction: Column<String?> = varchar("address",255).nullable()
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id,name = "PK_User_id")
}

@Serializable
data class User_data(
    val id: Int,
    val fullName: String,
    val email: String,
    val direction: String
    )
```

Services/ProductService.kt

```
package com.testreftul.Service

import com.testreftul.DbSettings.dbQuery
import com.testreftul.model.Product
import com.testreftul.model.Products
import com.testreftul.model.User
import com.testreftul.model.User_data
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SqlExpressionBuilder.eq
class ProductService {
    suspend fun addProduct(product:Product,us_id:User_data){
        dbQuery{
            Products.insert { pr->
                pr[Products.id]= product.id
                pr[Products.product_name] = product.food_name
                pr[Products.user_id] = us_id.id
            }

        }
    }
    suspend fun getProduct():List<Product?> = dbQuery {
        Products.selectAll().map { rowToProduct(it) }
    }

    suspend fun UpdateProduct(product: Product,id: Int){
        dbQuery {
            Products.update(
                where = {
                    Products.id.eq(id) and Products.id.eq(product.id)
                }
            ){pr ->
                pr[Products.product_name] = product.food_name
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun deleteProduct(id:Int){
        dbQuery {
            Products.deleteWhere { Products.id.eq(id) }
        }
    }

    private fun rowToProduct(row:ResultRow?):Product?{
        if (row == null){
            return null
        }
        return Product(
            id = row[Products.id],
            food_name = row[Products.product_name].toString(),

        )

    }

}
```

Services/UserService.kt

```
package com.testreftul.Service

import com.testreftul.DbSettings.dbQuery
import com.testreftul.model.Products
import com.testreftul.model.User
import com.testreftul.model.User_data
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.*

class UserService {
    suspend fun getAllCustomer(): List<User_data?> = dbQuery {
        User.selectAll().map { rowToUser(it) }
    }
   suspend fun addUser(user: User_data){
        dbQuery{
            User.insert { ur->
                ur[User.id] = user.id
                ur[User.fullName] = user.fullName
                ur[User.email] = user.email
                ur[User.direction] = user.direction
            }
        }
    }
    suspend fun getUserById(id: Int): User_data? = dbQuery {
        User.select {
            (User.id eq (id))
        }.mapNotNull { rowToUser(it) }
            .singleOrNull()
    }

    suspend fun deleteUserById(id: Int) = dbQuery {
        User.deleteWhere { User.id eq id } > 0
    }

     suspend fun updateUserById(user: User_data,id:Int) = dbQuery {
        User.update({User.id eq id}){
            it[fullName] = user.fullName
            it[email] = user.email
            it[direction] = user.direction
        }
    }



    private fun rowToUser(row: ResultRow?):User_data?{
        if (row == null){
            return null
        }
        return User_data(
            id = row[User.id],
            email = row[User.email].toString(),
            fullName = row[User.fullName].toString(),
            direction = row[User.direction].toString()
        )
    }
}
```

ProductRoutes.kt

```
package com.testreftul.controller

import com.testreftul.Service.ProductService
import com.testreftul.model.Product
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
val product_data = ProductService()
fun Route.ProductViews(){
    route("api/products"){
        get {
            val  allProdcuts = product_data.getProduct()
            call.response.status(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            call.respond(mapOf("Product" to allProdcuts))
        }
        post("{userId}") {
            val addProducts = call.receive<Product>()
            val user_id = user_data.getUserById(call.parameters["userId"]?.toInt()!!)
            if (user_id != null) {
                product_data.addProduct(addProducts,user_id)
            }else{
                call.respond("Error ")
            }
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        }
    }
}
```

UserRoutes.kt

```
package com.testreftul.controller

import com.testreftul.Service.UserService
import com.testreftul.model.User
import com.testreftul.model.User_data
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*

val user_data = UserService()
fun Route.UserViews() {
    route("api/customers") {
        get {
            val allCustomers = user_data.getAllCustomer()
            call.response.status(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            call.respond(mapOf("Customers" to allCustomers))
        }

        post {
            val add_user = call.receive<User_data>()
            user_data.addUser(add_user)
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        }
        get("{id}") {

            val customer_id = user_data.getUserById(call.parameters["id"]?.toInt()!!)
            if (customer_id == null) {
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            } else {
                call.respond(customer_id)
            }
        }
        delete("{id}") {
            val removed = user_data.deleteUserById(call.parameters["id"]?.toInt()!!)
            if (removed){
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            }
            else{
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            }
        }
        put("{id}"){
            val id =  call.parameters["id"]?.toInt()!!
            val users= call.receive<User_data>()
            user_data.updateUserById(users,id)
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it without Ktor?

Comment: Have you solved it? How?